# Access a Function not within the Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

I have the javascript code below:

```
(function($){

    function JsBarcode(){
        //Some Code Here
    }

})(window.jQuery);

(function ($) {  
    JsBarcode();
    //calls a JsBarcode not within a scope
})(jQuery);
```

When running the code above, it gives the error below:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JsBarcode is not defined
```

I am trying to call a function, which is not within the scope. How will I be able to call it?

Comment: answer is pretty simple...you can't without restructuring so it is in scope. Could create a global object variable and assign a property of that object to reference the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:
- you change the structure so the second module is inside the first: parent scope is always visible.
- you change the first module exporting the function so that you can access it outside. sample below

```js
var firstModuleHandle = (function($){

    var JsBarcode = function(){
        //Some Code Here
        console.log("can access me?");
    }
    return {JsBarcode: JsBarcode};

})(window.jQuery);

(function ($) {  
    firstModuleHandle.JsBarcode();
    //calls a JsBarcode not within a scope
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `JsBarcode` is declared inside a anonymous function, so it is available only inside the limited scope of the anonymous function in which it is declared.

One possible solution is to move the declaration outside of the anonymous function

Another one is to use a global variable to store the reference to the function as given below

```
//declare it as a gloal variable
var JsBarcode;
(function ($) {

    //assign the value of JsBarcode as the function
    JsBarcode = function () {
        //Some Code Here
    }

})(window.jQuery);

(function ($) {
    JsBarcode();
    //calls a JsBarcode not within a scope
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not wanting to clutter global namespace can also make it a property of jQuery  ... a mini plugin

```
(function($){
    // assign to $ namespace
    $.JsBarcode = function (){
        //Some Code Here
    }

})(window.jQuery);

(function ($) {
    // call jQuery.JsBarcode()  
    $.JsBarcode();

})(jQuery);
```